# Check online status, for example by pinging

Tags: vb.net, ping, win-universal-app

I am developing an universal windows app for Windows 10 IoT using VB.NET. 
I am checking for two things - first is, if there is any network at all. I am using

```
Imports System.Net
NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable
```

for this. But what this does not tell me is if I really do have internet access, it only indicates if I am connected to a network.

Is there any way to ping an address (like 8.8.8.8)? I cannot find a solution.
The device will only be used for private purposes, the app will not be public, if that information is necessary.

Comment: You could try sending an HTTP request using `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` or creating a TCP connection using `Windows.Ntworking.Sockets.StreamSocket`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:
My.Computer.Network.Ping("192.168.1.1") to ping an ip 
or 
My.Computer.Network.Ping("www.google.com") to ping a url

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If My.Computer.Network.Ping("192.168.1.1") Then
        MsgBox("Connection ok")
    Else
        MsgBox("No Connection")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is only valid in regular Windows Forms (and maybe WPF) applications but not in Universal Apps, since the "My"-Namespace does not exist in them.

Comment: @user2694534 You can use the [Ping Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping).

Answer (score 1):

This proposal text shows you how to definetly connected to the internet.
For example it returns true if google.com is reachable. So you don't need any ping.

```
''' <summary>
''' check for a existing internet connection to www.google.com
''' </summary>
''' <returns>True if it's exist</returns>
Public Shared Function isConnected() As Boolean
    Try
        Dim addresslist As IPAddress() = Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.google.com")
        ' | ' addresslist holds a list of ipadresses to google
        ' | ' e.g  173.194.40.112                                       |
        ' | '                .116                                       |
        If addresslist(0).ToString().Length > 6 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As Sockets.SocketException
        ' | ' You are offline                   |
        ' | ' the host is unkonwn               |
        Return False
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```