# Check if IP address is valid in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ip, verify

I am working on windows forms application. I have text box in whichuser can write IP address and i want to check if it is correct or not. I am trying with error provider and with this function but nothing happens.How I can do this verification?

```
Public Function IsAddressValid(ByVal addrString As String) As Boolean

        Dim address As IPAddress = Nothing
        Return IPAddress.TryParse(addrString, address)

    End Function
```

Comment: Your function is a bool. It returns true if the look of the string may be an ip address, otherwise false. It will not check, if the ip-address exists. Ref. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: The source code of what??

Comment: how to do this verification? By Try Parse method ot the other way ?

Comment: Try this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936840/check-online-status-for-example-by-pinging

Comment: did you debug your code? use this `Dim i = IPAddress.TryParse(addrString, address)
        Return -1` code and say to us what the value of `i`?