# System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string " " to type 'Double' is not valid.'

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to make a vb windows forms application to ping an IP address or web address using the Windows CMD but instead of using the cmd directly, I am trying to simplify the process by building a GUI. it is made up of a TextBox for the input, A RichTextbox for the output and a button to run the command

the issue I'm having every time I run the attached code everything seems to work fine until I press the run button which seems to crash the app causing the following error

**Error Messages**

```
System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Conversion from string "1.1.1.1" to type 'Double' is not valid.
  Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(String Value)
   at WinFormsApp1.Form1.ActionNet(String File, String Text)
   at WinFormsApp1.Form1.CMDRun_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at Interop.User32.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.Interop.Mso.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(UIntPtr dwComponentID, msoloop uReason, Void* pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(msoloop reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(msoloop reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at WinFormsApp1.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args)

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

**Code**

```
'''
Function ActionNet(ByVal File As String, ByVal Text As String)
        Dim Gstart As New Process()
        Gstart.StartInfo.FileName = File
        Gstart.StartInfo.Arguments = -Text

        Gstart.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        Gstart.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        Gstart.EnableRaisingEvents = True

        Application.DoEvents()
        Gstart.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        Gstart.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False

        AddHandler Gstart.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Gstart_OutputData
        AddHandler Gstart.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Gstart_OutputData

        Gstart.Start()
        Gstart.BeginErrorReadLine()
        Gstart.BeginOutputReadLine()
        Return File
    End Function

    Delegate Sub UpdateTextBoxDelg(ByVal text As String)
    Dim myDelegate As UpdateTextBoxDelg = New UpdateTextBoxDelg(AddressOf UpdateTbox)

    Public Sub UpdateTbox(ByVal Text As String)
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(Text & System.Environment.NewLine)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Gstart_OutputData(ByVal sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(myDelegate, e.Data)
        Else
            UpdateTbox(e.Data)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CMDRun_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CMDRun.Click
        RichTextBox1.Text = ""
        ActionNet("ping 1.1.1.1", TextBox1.Text)
        RichTextBox1.Focus()
    End Sub

'''
```

Comment: This line `Gstart.StartInfo.Arguments = -Text` should simply be `Text` not `-Text`.  If you need the `-` in the string then it should be concatenated to `Text` .... `"-" + Text`
Additionally, for future questons, it's useful to indicate which line is in error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936840/check-online-status-for-example-by-pinging

Comment: You should set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project and set it as the default for new projects - it would have helped you with the problem that Anu6is pointed out. Maybe you meant `"-n " & Text` if you wanted to specify the number of pings, as "-4" and "-6" are for IPv4 and IPv6 respectively.

Comment: Also take a look at [Double.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-5.0) method